# Word for a description of the physical characteristics/range/habits of an animal or plant species?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

i.e. is there a word for something like an entry in a natural history dictionary? I poked around trying unsuccessfully to find one, and I'll probably just use "description", but I still have a nagging feeling that there's a word for this, something similar to using "morphology" or "pathology" as countable nouns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Biological description

is the term used by the University of [Miami](https://cc1.rsmas.miami.edu/slugs/bio-description.html) to include the morphology, behavior etc. of an animal.

Alternatively, lots of academic papers seem to use

> [biological synopsis](https://www.google.ca/search?q=biological%20synopsis&hl=fr&authuser=0&safe=on&gws_rd=ssl)

You can find here an example used by the [California Academy of Science](http://www.sengis.org/synopsis.php) for some type of shrew.

What's interesting is that the term encompasses **everything** related to biology: Phylogeny, taxonomy, morphology... See all the sub-sections they use below:

[image: biological synopsis]

And last, if you focus only on physical characteristics you could use

> [biological profile](http://www.sfu.museum/forensics/eng/analysez-analyze/profil-profile/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a 1980s bird guide that uses "(species) description" (the photos are in a separate section of plates). A more modern Audubon guide with the same layout uses "species account" but also a simple (if tautological in the context of a book) "text description"